# Conflicts with MS Office temporary files when using Offline Folders on Vista

Tags: samba, offline-files, windows-vista

We are using Offline Folders feature of Windows Vista to make files on network shares available when out of office. Mostly it is working, but every time I do a sync I get a lot of such errors:

> D500E7B8.tmp - A file was deleted on
>   this computer and changed on the
>   server while this computer was
>   offline.

There are hundreds of them. I always select all of them and choose resolution "Delete from both locations". But what is causing this and how can I avoid it?

I suspect the reason is that we are using Debian and Samba (3.4.7) on our file server. I've been looking for some Samba options that would cure this, but with no success. I learned that probably the cause is, that both Word and Excel are using specific pattern to change files - they never change the original file, but instead always write a new temporary file and rename it to original file, when you click Save. This is documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211632/?FR=1.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to simply consider excluding files with the .tmp extension.

This can be configured by policy **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\offline files\files not cached**.

See these pages for more details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms814364.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=811660
- https://web.archive.org/web/20160227000652/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jonathanh/archive/2004/12/09/279292.aspx

Comment: But that would mean, that I can't use my Word/Excel files when not connected to our office LAN?

Comment: No, it just means the tmp files will not replicate.

Comment: I've set the policy but still experiencing issues with Word not allowing the files to be saved.